# Sql Database error when registering user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

ASP.net beginner here

every time I fill out the registration form and click submit, I get a SQL error, which I have googled and tried many solutions to but just cannot seem to work. It worked previously and I have not modified any code and it has stopped working.

```
protected void click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\ForumDB.mdf") + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        conn.Open();
        string insertData;
        insertData = "insert into userdata(username, password, email, name, gender) VALUES (@username, @password, @email, @name, @gender)";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insertData, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Gender.Text);

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        Response.Write("Registration is Successful");

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Sql error looks like this:

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'RAVIRAIDD64\Rav'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)   > at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    > at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at registration.click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Discussion Forum\registration.aspx.cs:line 40 ClientConnectionId:d749a94b-e01b-4223-af38-2ddb87fa0b8d

Comment: So the username and password are correct?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @Sievajet the username and password of what sorry?

Comment: The user RAVIRAIDD64\Rav doesnt have permissions or the password is wrong

Comment: @Sievajet how do i grant the permissions for it?

Answer (score 0):

Either the user has no permissions on the database or the password is wrong. See this image how the grant permissions:

[image: permissions]

To grant remote access:

[image: remoteaccess]

Beware that this excludes the other possible firewalls that possibly blocks remote connections

Comment: thanks for that, i completed the steps. when i tried to register again i was faced with
[code] Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
@Sievajet

Comment: remote access was already granted, i am still receiving the Sql error